# Why does my icon not appear in the title bar?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have assigned an icon to my application from the Properties window in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio; the application's icon changed successfully but the title bar is still showing the default icon:

[image: The title bar, showing the default icon]

I've rebuilt my application but it still displays the default icon. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because forms have a different icaon configuration than the application. Set the icon on the form, not ONLY on the application.

Answer (score 6):

There is another reason why the icon might not show.

If the ControlBox property of the Form is set to False the icon will not show.

(Sounds like an undesired side effect)

Comment: Sorry this is so old, but it helped me out today!  Just wanted to add, it isn't an undesired side effect.  If you click on the icon you can do the same things you do with the ControlBox, minimize, maximize, close.  So if you turn off the ControlBox, icon has to go with it.

Answer (score 5):

I know that it is a very old issue but I can add the following comment :

Pay attention to the 'FormBorderStyle' property.
If 'FixedToolWindow' or 'SizableToolWindow' are selected, your icon will not appear, even if you specified an icon in the 'Icon' property.
I encountered the same issue.
Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

The form itself has an `Icon` property you need to set as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you using winform you need to set the icon property  of your main form

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you are using winforms or wpf - wpf will place the icon on all windows/forms unless overridden.

Winforms requires individually set icons.