# Form icon won't show in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

I am taking an introductory course in C# programming, and one of the objectives in my upcoming assignment is to include an icon, stored as a resource, in the WinForms application's main form (top left). All the properties of the Form are the default ones.

I have not been able to figure out why it won't work. I can create an icon resource, and it is accessible from code. The icon is named T32.ico.

```
this.Icon = Properties.Resources.T32;
```

It all compiles OK, but the actual icon showing is still the default one. I have tried 16x16 bmp and 32x32 bmp, both 8 bit and 32 bit versions.

If it matters, I'm running Windows 10 and using Visual Studio Community 2019, 16.8.2, and the application I'm writing is using .NET Framework 4.8.

Any guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547969/why-does-my-icon-not-appear-in-the-title-bar

Comment: Where are you setting this.Icon to the resource?

Comment: Compile the application and then run it from the executable. I have seen this happen before during debugging but it works when running from the .exe file.

Comment: Use [this](https://icoconvert.com/) free service to build a multi format icon. Submit a PNG and pick `Custom Sizes -> Multi-Size in one icon`. Select all sizes. Get the resulting Icon and add it to `Project-> Resources->Icons`. Set the Icon in the Form Constructor after `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: @shox, in the Form load event.

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of exploring all possible aspects, I think I found the root cause.

When creating an icon resource from within Visual Studio, there are automatically a set of different icon formats created, all within one single .ico file. The 32 bit icons are not possible to edit using the Visual Studio Image Editor, while the 8 bit icons are. For some reason, the application seems to default to one of the 32 bit icons.

By removing all but the 8 bit versions, I was able to make it work.